# How to add marker on image in reactJS with ZoomIn and ZoomOut

Tags: reactjs, image, annotations, marker, image-annotations

I want to add marker as a pointer on the image in my react application. Image should be able to zoom in zoom out. But point should not get zoom.
Anyone know the library for it or related stuff, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer !

Use library [**react-image-annotation-with-zoom**](https://github.com/Scriptor-Group/react-image-annotation#readme)